# Excel: How do I limit sig figures and incorporate a value into an equation with an asterisk?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I recently had to qualify a result for my lab by including `&"*"` in the equation with a note at the bottom. When I do this, some values increase the sig figs dramatically and I am unable to reduce the sig figs by traditional means. I am assuming the asterisks is causing the issue. Additionally, I am unable to include the asterisked value into the next linked equation for the same reason. Any advice is welcome.

Code is as follows:

```
=IF(I34="","",IF(O34=">","",IF(SUM(M34:M36)=0,N37,AVERAGE(M34:M36)))&"*")
```

Additionally, second equation will not compute value due to asterisk

Comment: Change the number format of the cell to add a `*` suffix, and remove the `&"*"` from your formula(s).

Comment: Thank  you! Which is the best option in number format to add an asterisk? I tried selecting the cell and then in number format -->custom--> @"*" and it did not effectively make the change

Comment: Something like `0.00"*"`.

Comment: I was able to fool around with a few combinations and was able to get it to work. Thank you again!